# webpack load amd path modules dependency

Tags: npm, amd

I am testing the loading of modules in webpack. How would you indicate the path of the dependency in an AMD module?

My project has something like this:

```
 ├── modules
 │   ├── mod1.js
 │   ├── mod2.js
 │   └── others
 │       └── mod3.js
 ├── public
 │   └── bundle.js
 ├── src
 │   └── app
 │       └── app.js
 └── webpack.config.js
```

in app.js I import only mod3.js therefore you must compile the three JS (mod1, mod2, mod3) since mod3.js depend on them.

I have a "others" route. Every time I create a folder I have to include the following line in webpack.config.js?

```
  path.resolve(__dirname, 'modules/others'),
```

Is it not possible to indicate the path of the dependency in the module itself without webpack compiling go to the hard defined in the config?

Thank you